# Recyclerview item loading from first one instead

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Recently I have come across a project that requires a continuous list that is linked with a list of menu.
Something like :

PIC 1-----PICTURE  PICTURE
PIC 2-----PICTURE  PICTURE
PIC 3-----PICTURE  PICTURE
PIC 4-----PICTURE  PICTURE
PIC 5-----PICTURE  PICTURE

So the **LEFT** side menu controls the **RIGHT** size view and the **RIGHT** side view is a continuous list.
It works like this : 
When I press on **PIC 1**, the **RIGHT** side shows **PIC 1 information**.
The **RIGHT** side is also scrollable from **PIC 1** to **PIC 2** information and when I scroll **pass** **PIC 1** it should shows **PIC 2 information** on the **RIGHT**. 
I used nested recyclerview for this and what happens is that when trying to scroll from **PIC 2** to **PIC 1** it will not load the bottom of **PIC 1** first but instead it is trying to load the **PIC 1** top head view. 
There is this half cut image when scrolling from **PIC 2** to **PIC 1** because the view is being recycled.
Is there any solution to this issue ?

Comment: Are you want to restore recycled state of previous nested recycler view when scroll back to PIC 1??

Comment: when scrolling from PIC 2 back to PIC1, it will sometimes recycled and thus making it load from start, what I need is either to make it consistent and not load from beginning(I tried to turn of recycled but seems buggy) or any other solution to do this view.

Answer (score 0):

In Parent Recycler view declare:

```
private final Map<Integer, Parcelable> parcelableMap = new HashMap<>();
```

After that override `onViewRecycled()` and save the LayoutManager state as `Parcelable`.

```
    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
      
            final int position =  holder.getAdapterPosition();
            if (holder.layoutManager != null)
                parcelableMap.put(position, holder.layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState()));
       
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    }
```

Make LayoutManager class as a variable in holder class in which we are using Nested recycler view:

```
public class ItemRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LayoutManager layoutManager;
        ......
}
```

And in `onBindViewHolder` :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Parcelable parcelable = parcelableMap.get(position);
    holder = ..;
    if (parcelable != null && holder.layoutManager != null)
             holder.layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(parcelable);
```